# Try to get sub array With given Range

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

While try to get sub array With given Range at that time this error.

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[Info]' with an index of type 'CountableRange<Int>' .
```

My code is

Info Modal

```
class Info : NSObject {
    var type : Type = .Unknown
    var data = ""

    init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Array declaration

```
var currentData : [Info] = []
```

While trying this code

```
let moreAnimals: [Info] = self.currentData[0..<5] //above error disply.
```

Comment: you need to add custom subscript to your info class . for more refer :https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH16-ID305

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let currentData = [Info(), Info(), Info()]
let subarr0 = currentData[0..<2] // ArraySlice<Info>
let subarr1 = Array(currentData[0..<2]) // Array<Info>
```

Answer (score -2):

to fetch range of element from generics collection we need to convert to NSArray and fetch the element in range using subarrayWithRange Method.

```
var moreAnimals: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

var otherarr: [Int] = (moreAnimals as NSArray).subarray(with: NSMakeRange(0, 5)) as! [Int]
```

output ::
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]